# adding line break after a div element

Tags: html, css

I have a list of div in a parent div element, each child div element contains a button. I want to add a line break after every 4th child div element

```
<div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">+</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">-</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">*</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">/</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">7</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">8</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">9</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">C</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">4</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">5</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">6</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">%</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">1</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">2</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">3</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">=</button></div>
</div>
```

How can i do that in css?
i tried

```
.btn{
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
```

}

```
 .btn-div{
  display: inline-block;
```

}

```
.btn-container div:nth-of-type(4n)::after{
  content: '\A';
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided seems to be working on JSFiddle

```
.btn-container div:nth-of-type(4n)::after{
    content: '\A';
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vg089jhr/

What results are you getting? Is the CSS file being read correctly?

Comment: i want four horizontal button and then a line break

Comment: Change .btn-div from inline-block to just inline

Answer (score 2):

Add this css using float

```css
.btn-container div{
  float:left;
}
.btn-container div:nth-child(4n){
    float:none;
    height:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">+</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">-</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">*</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">/</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">7</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">8</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">9</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">C</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">4</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">5</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">6</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">%</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">1</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">2</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">3</button></div>
    <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">=</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be by using `<br>` code, it will break line/ add a line before the next div for example:

`<div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">+</button></div>
 <br>
 <div class="btn-div"><button class="btn">-</button></div>`